# Can I randomize the order of inline buttons?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

In the process of making a inline telegram bot. I have 2 buttons that show under a message. Is there a way to force these buttons to always change places in between eachother? Sometimes button 1 is in row 1 and sometimes to have button 2 be in row 1.

```
Emojihash: str =emojihash.eh1("unique code",5)


EmojiCode: str = emojihash.eh1("unique password" + SellerUserName + str(update.inline_query.from_user.id), 5)



keyboard = [
            [                                                                     
                InlineKeyboardButton(EmojiCode, callback_data=str(ONE)),
            ],
            [
                            InlineKeyboardButton(Emojihash, callback_data=str(TWO)),

            ],
        ]
            reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
            context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.inline_query.from_user.id,text=verified_message_1, reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Also is there a way to make the Emojihash variable take 5 random emojis each time it's called?

Looked for documentation, but didn't find anything other than how to randomize strings, integers and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

[`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) will help you to randomize the order of the `keyboard` list.

Keep in mind that `random.shuffle()` shuffles sequence in place (the original list (`keyboard`) will be shuffled) and returns `None`

P.S. I didn't work with Emojihash, so can't help with it. I think it is better to post a new question for it.